# Perl, unknown result of the `map` function

Tags: arrays, perl

I get a very strange result in `print @squares` array below;
I should have got 49 but I get some random number:

```
@numbers={-1,7};

my @squares = map { $_ > 5 ? ($_ * $_) : () } @numbers;

print @squares;
```

$ perl g.pl

12909907697296

Comment: Hint: `print @numbers` or `print 0+$numbers[0]`. Then add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of all of your perl scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```perl
@numbers={-1,7};
```

`{ }` builds a hash and returns a reference to the hash. The above is equivalent to

```perl
my %anon = ( -1 => 7 );
@numbers = \%anon;
```

A reference treated as a number returns the underlying pointer as a number, so you get garbage.

---

To populate an array, use

```perl
my @numbers = ( -1, 7 );
```

`-1, 7` returns two numbers, which are added to the array when assigned to the array. (The parens aren't special; they just override precedence like in math.)

---

The complete program:

```perl
use 5.014;      # ALWAYS use `use strict;` or equivalent! This also provides `say`.
use warnings;   # ALWAYS use `use warnings;`!

my @numbers = ( -1, 7 );

my @squares = map { $_ > 5 ? ($_ * $_) : () } @numbers;

# Print each number on a separate line.
# Also provides the customary final line feed.
say for @squares;
```

Alternative:

```perl
my @squares =
   map { $_ * $_ }
      grep { $_ > 5 }
         @numbers;
```

Comment: Right. But now what is the difference between `use 5.014;`      and  `use strict; ` ?

Comment: `use 5.014;` requires Perl 5.14, but it also implies `use strict;` (for ≥5.012) and `use feature "5.014";`. The latter provides `say` a couple of other features. I could technically have used `use 5.010;`, or even the most limited `use strict; use feature qw( say );`. But 5.14 is widely available and something like 9 years old now.

Comment: That should be `use feature ':5.14';`.

Answer (score 2):

Your line `@numbers={-1,7}` does not create a list of multiple integers. In Perl, an expression with curly braces denotes a *hash reference literal*. This could be written more clearly as:

```perl
my @numbers = ({ "-1" => 7 });
```

So that is a list of one item, which is a hash reference.

Later, you use the hash reference as a number. When you use a reference as a number, it is converted to its memory address, which is some unspecified large number. That is what you're seeing.

To create an inclusive range in Perl, use the `..` operator:

```perl
my @numbers = -1..7;
```

To just spell out all items in a list, enclose it in parentheses `( )`:

```perl
my @numbers = (-1, 7);
```

Comment: Re "*To create an inclusive range in Perl, use the `..` operator*", You had me convinced my answer was not quite right, except I then noticed the OP said "*I should have got 49*". +1 for saying expected result!

Comment: @ikegami Very good point. I was somehow thinking about Mathematica where a tuple like `{-1, 7}` would sometimes be used to denote an interval.

Comment: @ikegami I'm new here. What does it mean to say "`+1` for saying expected result" ?

Comment: @user2925716 Ikegami is saying that you asked a very good question because you both showed what you did and what you expected to happen. The `+1` is used to indicate an upvote.